# how to rewrite jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, mootools

In an attempt to circumvent a MooTool/JQuery conflict with this idea :: http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-mootools

I am under the impression that I have to rewrite the NIVO function.  Not being a JS coder, it is not clear to me if I can substitute one function with the other, or if a rewrite is necessary.

This is the format of the call

```
(function($) {
    $('p').css('color','#ff0000');
 })(jQuery);
```

Do I need to rewrite this to avoid conflict with MooTools?

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect:'sliceDown', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown, or random'
    animSpeed:1000, //Slide transition speed
    pauseTime:6000,
    startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)
    directionNav:false, //Next & Prev
    controlNav:false //1,2,3...
});
});
```

Comment: Did you try simply changing your code to jQuery("#slider").nivoSlider(...); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either encapsulate all your jQuery calls in an anonymous function where you pass $ as an argument and finish with (jQuery) as in the above code. This requires all jQuery calls to be inside a function like this. This is the default format for jQuery plugins, by the way.

Or you can put jQuery in no conflict mode like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then you need to make sure none of your jQuery code uses $ since mootools wants that. Instead use jQuery explicitly. So instead of:

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider...
```

you need:

```
jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... i was search around 2 hours, finally found solution through your reply... thanks a lot once again.